# Boa Constructor can't find Python 2.7

Tags: python, installation, boa-constructor

On the install screen for Boa Constructor, it says Python 2.2 and 3.1 were found in the registry, however I use 2.7 as my main version. How can I get it to recognise it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Boa Constructor isn't alive. The last news posted on his site dates from 2006. So maybe it wont recognize recent python versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on the python version.
I already tested on Windows OS.

- Boa Constructor can detect python-2.5.4
- Boa Constructor can detect python 2.6.6.
- Boa Constructor can also detect python 3.4.4 but
- Boa Constructor can't detect python 3.4.3
- Boa Constructor can't detect python 2.7.12.

I am still doing try and error with others version than begin with 2.7.x. 
I think it will consume so many time for me to get the 2.7.x correct version for BOA Constructor. 
But (I just share my Experience) If you want Boa Constructor on Windows working very good you need this correct versions of them so I have downloaded and tested and it's working, here come the list of correct version that not conflict each other.

1. python-2.5.4.msi.
2. boa-constructor-0.6.1.src.win32.exe.
3. wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.10.1-py25.exe (optional) as GUI.
4. MySQL-python-1.2.2.win32-py2.5.exe (optional) as mySQL Connector.
5. xlutils-1.4.1.win32.exe (optional) for Ms Excel access.
6. xlwt-0.7.2.win32.exe (optional) for Ms Excel access.
7. xlrd-0.7.9.win32.exe (optional) for Ms Excel access.